# Java keypressed doesn't work with french accents keycode = 0

Tags: java, keyboard, keypress, keyevent

I am using Ubuntu in french with a azerty keyboard, and every key with an accent (é è...) has 0 for its keycode.

KeyPressed/released works well with other keys, but I would also need it to work with "é" "è" "à" "ù"...

How to make it work? Any other way to do it please?

Edit : Here is the code :

```
import java.awt.Event;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

public class KeyHandler implements KeyListener {

    private Screen screen;
    private Screen.KeyTyped keyTyped;

    public KeyHandler(Screen screen) {
        this.screen = screen;

        this.keyTyped = this.screen.new KeyTyped(screen);
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
        System.out.println(keyCode);

        //this one works well for backspace for instance
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE) {
            this.keyTyped.keyBACKSPACE();
        }

        //many others keys which work
        ...
   }
```

}

With this System.out.println I get the keycode of the keys :

I want to map the second row, it is the one between F1 F2 F3 ... and AZERTYUIOP, and the keys in this row are :  & é " ' ( - è _ ç à ) =

When I try my program, the results of the println are :

& 150

é 0

" 152

' 222

( 519

- 45

è 0

_ 523

ç 0

à 0

) 522

= 61

So it works for most keys, but for any non english letter, there is a problem, the keycode is 0, which I believe means java doesn't know which key it is (
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html

```
public static final int     KEY_LOCATION_UNKNOWN    0
```

)

So my question is, how to have a keycode for those very usual keys of the french keyboard?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [KeyCodes for azerty keyboard in JAVA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21204894/keycodes-for-azerty-keyboard-in-java)

Comment: No it is not a duplicate. arrow keys work very well for me.  37 38 39 40.  I am asking about keys that are not recognized (their keycode is 0)

Comment: Do you just want to get the keycode or convert it to initial character?
Can you share your code please?

Comment: Thank you for you answer, I just edited my post to add the code and another explanation.   I want to be able to write in my program "when the user press the key "é",  call the function X"      It works for most keys. But it doesn't work if the keys have 0 as a keycode , because i can't  write "if keycode == 0" . There are several keys with 0 as a keycode, so I can't distinguish  them.  I hope it is more clear now. Thank you